# Geckodriver suddenly stopped working after a while and log stopped generating

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Following is geckdriver log.

```
JavaScript warning: https://xxxxx, line 1: String.toLowerCase is deprecated; use String.prototype.toLowerCase instead
1571180445730   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 56930
[Child 11304, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 11304, [Parent 15620, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 18764, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 1876[Parent 15620, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 18528, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 18521571193870646    mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.wefGvenxtjuS"
1571193871155   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1571193871155   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1571193874489   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59485
1571193874542   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript error: https://xxxxx, line 2: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
console.error: BroadcastService: 
  receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for
  remote-settings/monitor_changes
  threw error:
  Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource..
  Stack:
    remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:750:13

JavaScript warning: https://xxxxx, line 1: String.toLowerCase is deprecated; use String.prototype.toLowerCase instead
1571195357820   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 59485
[Parent 16976, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 19196, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 15192, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 1[Parent 16976, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 17100, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 1
```

The log stopped generating here and geckodriver has no any action even I force to close Firefox browser.
The testing script also cannot be terminated.

For the most part, if I force to close browser, testing will be terminated and fail the test.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Below is my firefox settings:

```
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    fp.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
    fp.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.auto", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.doorhanger", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.service.enabled", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.url", "https://do.not.update")
    fp.set_preference("app.update.checkInstallTime", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.silent", True)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.download.attempts", 0)
    fp.set_preference("browser.search.update", False)
    fp.set_preference("extensions.update.enabled", False)
    fp.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.extensions.update.enabled", False)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.interval", 2592000)
    fp.set_preference("app.update.link.updateAvailableWhatsNew", "no-update-available-whats-new")
    fp.set_preference("app.update.link.updateManualWhatsNew", "no-update-manual-whats-new")
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference(downloadDIR, os.getcwd())
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,text/csv,text/html,application/octet-stream,application/force-download,application/pdf,application/binary,application/json,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/zip")
    fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: geckodriver v26 came out a few days ago: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0. What version of geckodriver and firefox are you running?  Update to FF v69 and geckodriver v26 and see if your issue persists...YMMV.

Comment: @orde I use geckodriver 26ver. and Firefox 64ver.

Comment: Thank you all. I find the problem in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is some permission issue.
1571193871155   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1571193871155   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*

The script you are running does not have permission to access the extension you are trying to access using your script.

Comment: Thank you! But I saw that this warning message appears many times. I don't know why it will stop working after a while.